# convertion of a class to arc from non-arc

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi all,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myindex;
```

this line changes to **unsafe_unretained** after performing a convertion to Objective C ARC can any one please explain me regarding this.

Comment: That's a primitive type. It should stay as `assign`.

Comment: Agreed. Other [setter semantics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2) of weak/strong/etc. make no sense with primitive types. And as assigned is the default, it's not even necessary. As that doc says "You use this attribute [`assign`] for scalar types such as `NSInteger` and `CGRect`."

Comment: It's generally logical to replace `assign` with `weak` (or if you're supporting pre-iOS 5, `unsafe_unretained`), but in the context of a scalar type, it makes no sense. Keep scalars `assign` or omit the setter semantics altogether. So, yes, `assign` is to `weak`/`unsafe_unretained` as `retain` is to `strong`, but none of that makes any sense with scalars. Keep them `assign` or omit the qualifier altogether.

Comment: @lochana Are you saying that the automatic ARC conversion tool changed this from `assign` to `unsafe_unretained`? If so, is the property really defined as `@property (nonatomic, assing) NSInteger *myindex;`? In other words, is this property really defined as an NSInteger pointer and you just forget the asterisk when you posted the code in the question? If not, it would make no sense for the ARC conversion to make such a change (and it is probably a mistake that the property is setup as a pointer).

Comment: Lochana : Kindly dont accept a wrong answer. You can simply check "number of downvotes", and it will mislead to all SO users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it won't change to `unsafe_unretained` because it is a scalar value.
Probably you wrote like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *myindex;
```

that's why it is converting to `unsafe_unretained`.

In ARC `assign` is effectively `unsafe_unretained`.

For scalars values like `int`, `float`. You can use `assign` itself.
For objects you can use either `weak` or `unsafe_unretained`, it depends on the context.

`unsafe_unretained` and `weak` prevent the retention of objects, but in slightly different ways.

- `weak` the pointer to an object will convert to nil when the object is deallocated.
- `unsafe_unretained` will continue pointing to the memory where an object was, even after it was deallocated. This can lead to crashes due to accessing that deallocated object.

Answer (score 2):

_unsafe_unretained is a variable qualifier.

From [transition to ARC documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> __unsafe_unretained specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive and is not set to nil when there are no strong
>   references to the object. If the object it references is deallocated,
>   the pointer is left dangling.

Simply, if you use this qualifier, it won't do any retain for you, and it won't automatically set its reference to nil, when there are no other object is retaining it.

### EDIT: After seeing the comment

First thing first, the variable in question is a primitive type (`NSInteger`, like `CGFloat`, `float` etc). So variable qualifiers like `__weak`, `__strong`, `__unsafe_unretained` has no effect on them. So there is no danger in below code.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myindex;
```

Now if in some other parts, you have a non primitive type, like NSString, UIImage etc, with this qualifier, then you must make sure you retain the variable, throughout the time of your use, and release them after.

Comment: thanks but can you tell me will this cause any danger in my code say for instance if i use this variable across classes sorry if this is a very basic question since i am a part time ios programmer